# Variable is instance of Enum

Tags: javascript, instanceof

I have the following javascript code:

```
function testClass() {
    this.SaveValue = function (value) {
        var isInstance = value instanceof TestEnum;

        if (!isInstance) {
            return;
        }
     }
}

TestEnum = {
    VALUE_0: 0,
    VALUE_1: 1,
    VALUE_2: 2   
}
```

I create an instance of this object in the following way:

```
$(function () {
    var a = new testClass();
    a.SaveValue(TestEnum.VALUE_1);    
});
```

All I'd like to do is test that the value passed to the `SaveValue` function is actually the type of `TestEnum`. However, when I run this code I get the following error: `Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got 1`

Am I going about this the right way? I tried typeof but it only returns `number` which is not particularly useful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a number to the function in

```
a.SaveValue(TestEnum.VALUE_1);
```

Since TestEnum is simply an Object, and you are referencing a number property on that object, you're calling your function with a number.  You should instead create a TestEnumValue object and use that for your Object's properties:

[JSFiddle link for below](http://jsfiddle.net/Andypro/7mfQd/)

```
function testClass() {
    this.SaveValue = function (value) {
        var isInstance = value instanceof TestEnumValue;

        if (!isInstance) {
            return;
        }
     }
}

TestEnumValue = function(arg) {
   arg = arg ? arg : 0;  //  sensible default

   this.key = 'VALUE_' + arg;
   this.val = arg;
}

Level = {
    NumSpiders : new TestEnumValue(0),
    NumCreepers: new TestEnumValue(1),
    NumZombies : new TestEnumValue(2),
    NumChickens: new TestEnumValue  //  uses default enum value    
};

$(function() {
    var a = new testClass();
    a.SaveValue(Level.NumSpiders);

    $('#hi').text(Level.NumSpiders.key);
});
```

Comment: Fantastic stuff - just what I need!

Comment: Although this answers my question, it does bring a new problem to mind  - when `SaveValue` is called it can be passed in a new `TestEnumValue` directly with any value in the constructor. I suppose there's no way around that....

Comment: You could harden the TestEnumValue to handle undefined `arg`s and just have it return the default key and value of your choice - see my edited answer.

Comment: I don't want to discredit this answer, but isn't it essentially the same as mine? ;)

Answer (score 5):

You could create the values as instances of the "class":

```
function TestEnum(value) {
    this._value = value;
}

TestEnum.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this._value;
}

TestEnum.prototype.toString = function() {
    return 'TestEnum_' + this._value;
}

TestEnum.VALUE_0 = new TestEnum(0);
TestEnum.VALUE_1 = new TestEnum(1);
```

The following would work then:

```
TestEnum.VALUE_0 instanceof TestEnum
```

But it also means you'd have to explicitly access the numerical value of one value with `.valueOf`. In some cases JS will do this automatically for you (like in `5 + TestEnum.VALUE_1`). Overriding `toString` so that you can use a value as property might also be necessary.

It really depends on your use case whether this is a viable solution.

---

Alternatively, if just want to test whether a value is part of the enum, you can have an additional property which holds all possible values:

```
TestEnum.values = {0: true, 1: true, ...};
```

And then test it with

```
value in TestEnum.values
// or more reliable (fails for inherited `Object` properties)
TestEnum.values.hasOwnProperty(value);
```

You could even automate this:

```
function collectValues(obj) {
    var values = {}; // or Object.create(null) if available
    for (var prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
            values[obj[prop]] = true;
        }
    }
    return values;
}

TestEnum.values = collectValues(TestEnum);
```

This will only reliably work for primitive values though and won't distinguish between the string `"1"` and the number `1`.

Comment: Interesting. Really, what I'm trying to do here is restrict the value that can be passed into that function to a certain subset of valid values. I could just go the simple route of saying `if value == 1 || 2 || 3` etc, but I thought it would be a little more maintainable and make the code easier to read if I used a custom type rather than just throwing meaningless integers around.

Comment: Well, you could also just have a map with valid values: `TestEnum.values = {0: true, 1: true, ...}` and test a value with `value in TestEnum.values`.

Answer (score 2):

Playing around with this, I noticed that you can leverage the fact that an enum compiles into an object that binds the values both ways combined with a `hasOwnProperty` check.

```
export enum TEST_ENUM{
    ZERO, // 0
    ONE, // 1
    TWO, // 2
}

let a = 1;
let b = TEST_ENUM.TWO // 2
let c = 5 // incorrect value

TEST_ENUM.hasOwnProperty(a); // TRUE
TEST_ENUM.hasOwnProperty(b); // TRUE
TEST_ENUM.hasOwnProperty(c); // FALSE
```

This comes with a few caveats though;

```
// An object's keys are always strings...
// Although this shouldn't not matter usually (e.g. parsed user input)
TEST_ENUM.hasOwnProperty("2"); // TRUE

// And the enum is bound two-way so:
let input = "TWO";
if (TEST_ENUM.hasOwnProperty(input) { // TRUE
  let result = input // "TWO"
  // result is now the enum's value, instead of the key.
  result = TEST_ENUM[input]; // this would be the correct assignment
};
```

Of course you can fix both of these with a `typeof` check, in case of a string assign it `TEST_ENUM[mystring]`.

Note that my intellisense didn't autocomplete the `hasOwnProperty` function on an enum, but it doesn't complain about it either, and it's available on all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**

[Here's an example of how you could do it.](http://jsfiddle.net/hL5L6/3/)

```
function TestEnum(val) {
    this.vals = this.vals || [];
    if (this.vals.indexOf(val) == -1) console.log('nope: ' + val);
    else console.log('ok: ' + val);
}
(function() {
    var vals = {
        VALUE_0: 0,
        VALUE_1: 1,
        VALUE_2: 2
    };
    TestEnum.prototype.vals = [];
    for (var key in vals) {
        TestEnum[key] = vals[key];
        TestEnum.prototype.vals.push(vals[key]);
    }
})();
```

Now `new TestEnum(TestEnum.VALUE_0);` is OK, but if you try, say, `new TestEnum(3)`, then it throws an exception.

---

This is a bit backwards -- `x instanceof y` means that x has been created as `x = new y()`.  Since `TestEnum` isn't even a function, you can't create an instance of it, so this isn't going to work.

What you could do is maybe something like this:

```
function MyEnum(enumVal) { this.val = enumVal; }
a.SaveValue( new MyEnum(TestEnum.VALUE_1) );
```

Then check using `isInstance = value instanceof MyEnum`.

Comment: Interesting idea - but it doesn't help me restrict values to an allowable range (see my comment on Felix King's answer).